# How do I add an authentication system for cURL on Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, authentication, curl, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to do a small project and while testing things I discovered I can do cURL requests from any server to my Firebase Database (tested on an online php tester), so I'm considering this is a security flaw for my project and I have been looking for a method to add some kind of password for cURL requests, but I found nothing, at least nothing I could understand. I know firebase have rules to manage who can read or write on my database, but I didnt find something that could filter requests by server or only allow requests that have an special password sent as parameter.
So my question is if there is a way to do something like that I could use on my project so only cURL requests made for me would work.

Here it is one of my cURL requests, in case it helps for resolving my problem.

```
$url = "https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/profile/messages/".$_COOKIE['cookiename'].".json";

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $data = json_decode($response, true);
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

UPDATE: I found this, I think it could be the thing I need, but Im missing the part where I tell the database to ask for the access token. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth).

In particular, "you can sign in a user with an email and password by issuing an HTTP POST request to the Auth verifyPassword endpoint", see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).

Then you can use the user's uid in your Firebase security rules, in order to protect your database.

Answer (score 0):

You should read and understand the [documentation for the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).  If you want to bypass security rules that would normally apply to web and mobile users, you will need to generate an OAuth token for a service account that has permissions to access your database, and use that in your requests.

If you don't want public access to your database, you will have to set up [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to limit that.  To stop all public access, your rules should be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked,

with one TestController:

get access_token using google/apiclient library in Laravel(php8),

This access_token works with any project in 1 firebase

https://github.com/linhdv96/cUrl-firebase-remote-config